# Setting up MySQL for dev environment with Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

Trying to set up a docker mysql server with phpmyadmin and an existing company_dev.sql file to import, in an effort to dockerize my dev environment.

My first question is how do I go about setting this up? Do I need to specify an OS, i.e. Ubuntu in my Dockerfile, then add sudo apt-get install mysql-server and install phpmyadmin? Or am I better off running an existing docker image from the docker repo and building on top of that?

Upon making CRUD operations to this database, I would like to save its state for later use. Would using docker commit be appropriate for this use case? I know using dockerfile is best practice.

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I have used this Dockerfile in order to restore MySQL data.

- [GitHub - stormcat24/docker-mysql-remote](https://github.com/stormcat24/docker-mysql-remote)

> My first question is how do I go about setting this up?

This dockerfile is using `mysqldump` to load from real env/save to docker env. You can also do that. Actually, it will load/save whole tables in your specified database.

> Do I need to specify an OS, i.e. Ubuntu in my Dockerfile, then add sudo apt-get install mysql-server and install phpmyadmin?

You can see this docker image is created from [DockerHub - library/mysql](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/mysql/) , we don't need to prepare basic middle-wares except phpmyadmin.

> Or am I better off running an existing docker image from the docker repo and building on top of that?

It's better to use already existing Docker repository !

> Upon making CRUD operations to this database, I would like to save its state for later use. Would using docker commit be appropriate for this use case? I know using dockerfile is best practice.

I have tried this also. After some testing, I successfully saved a docker image contains MySQL DB. To do that, we just need to exec `docker commit xxx` after finished your build. However be careful, don't push your image file to DockerHub.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with docker you should have a single service/Daemon per container. In your case, mysql and phpmyadmin should go in different containers. This is not mandatory (there are workarounds) but makes things a lot easier.

In order to avoid reinventing the wheel, you should IMHO always use existing images for the wanted service, expecially if they're official ones. But again, you can choose for any reason to start from scratch (a base image such as "Ubuntu" or "Debian" just to name two) and install the needed stuff.

About the storage question: docker containers should always be immutable. If a container needs to save it's state, it should use `volumes`. Volumes are a way to share a folder between the container and the host. For instance, the official mysql image uses a volume to store the database files.

So, to summarize, you should use ready images when possible and no, using git commit to store mysql data is not a good practice.